# Does System.Diagnostic.Process.Start() runs a .exe file correctly

Tags: c#

I have written a simple console application in C# that takes two arguments. these two arguments are the name of input file and output file. This console app reads the data from input file and writes them to a new file with the output argument name. this program works correctly, when I run this program from CMD (command prompt) it works and the output file is created.
But when I run this app from an other windows application that runs this below line, that was not create the file.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Users\Khodaei\Desktop\testExecuter\testExecuter\bin\Debug\testExecuter.exe", "input.csv output.csv");
```

Is there any limitation for running an .exe file from `System.Diagnostic.Process.Start()`?

Comment: Are you sure it is writing to the right location? I guess it just writes at the current directory, which is **not** your Debug folder.

Comment: No, there are no limitations in this regard. Your expectations are wrong. This code _will_ run `testExecuter.exe input.csv output.csv`. Whether _that_ does what you expect it to, depends on what you expect and how `testExecuter.exe` is programmed.

Comment: I want to write the file in the Debug folder of the target .exe file, that i want to run it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can never be sure that the relative path will yield an absolute path that is within the desired directory. And that is exactly your problem here.

You should either provide an absolute path to both arguments within the second parameter of `Process.Start`, or make sure that the working directory is set as desired. Note that if a path contains spaces, you have to wrap it around in `""`.

Comment: No, you **must** not. It is an option, but you can also just make sure the working directory is set correctly.

Comment: You could also do that, but the most reliable way is to provide absolute paths.

Comment: I agree, but depending on the context, that may or may not be a possibility. The launching application may not know the expected full path, for example, but assumes the files to be present in the working directory. :)